# Duvidas LEFT JOIN SQL

Tags: sql

Preciso fazer uma query, onde eu informo um código de pessoa e a sql me retorna todas as pessoas que estão dentro daquele grupo que está a pessoa a qual eu digitei o código.

Exemplo:
Insiro código '1', O código refere ao código da pessoa, esta pessoa está em uma turma 'A', porem na turma 'A' existe mais pessoas, preciso pegar todas as pessoas desta turma 'A'. Existe a possibilidade da pessoa ter mais de uma TURMA, ai preciso pegar todas PESSOAS de TODAS AS TURMAS DAQUELE CÓDIGO que informei.

Até o momento conseguir fazer uma bagunça, porem está voltando 2 linhas como null e traz o restante correto.

```
select Q5.* from
( select * FROM tbl_TURMA) Q1
left join
( select * from tbl_PESSOA_TURMA WHERE COD_IDENT_PESSO = '38'  ) Q2
on Q1.COD_IDENT_TURMA = Q2.COD_IDENT_TURMA
left join
( select * from tbl_PESSOAS ) Q3
on Q2.COD_IDENT_PESSO = Q3.COD_IDENT_PESSO
left join
(select * from tbl_PESSOA_TURMA) Q4
on Q4.COD_IDENT_TURMA = Q2.COD_IDENT_TURMA
left join
(select * from tbl_PESSOAS) Q5
on Q4.COD_IDENT_PESSO = Q5.COD_IDENT_PESSO

TURMAS | ALUNOS | TURMAS_ALUNOS
1      | 1      | 1 - 1
2      | 2      | 1 - 2
3      | 3      | 2 - 1 
       | 4      | 2 - 5
       | 5      | 1 - 6
       | 6      | 3 - 6

A minha SQL com o CÓDIGO de ALUNO 1 neste caso deveria retornar:
ALUNOS 1,2,6,5
Pois o aluno 1 está na turma 1, e juntamente com ele está o aluno 2 e aluno 6.
Porem o aluno 1 também está na turma 2, e juntamente com ele o aluno 5
```

Comment: Você não quer que repita? Então qual turma irá aparecer para pessoa que está em duas turmas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente utilizar a seguinte query, irá retornar todas pessoas que participarem do grupo da pessoa inserida na condição.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    PESSOAS.* 
FROM 
    TBL_PESSOAS PESSOAS
    LEFT JOIN TBL_PESSOA_TURMA AS PT ON PT.COD_IDENT_PESSO = PESSOAS.COD_IDENT_PESSO
    LEFT JOIN TBL_TURMA AS TURMA ON TURMA.COD_IDENT_TURMA = PT.COD_IDENT_TURMA
WHERE   
    TURMA.COD_IDENT_TURMA IN (
                            SELECT 
                                DISTINCT(PT.COD_IDENT_TURMA)
                            FROM 
                                TBL_PESSOA_TURMA PT
                                LEFT JOIN TBL_PESSOAS AS PESSOAS ON PESSOAS.COD_IDENT_PESSO = PT.COD_IDENT_PESSO
                            WHERE 
                                PESSOAS.COD_IDENT_PESSO = '38'
                           )
```

Comment: Deu tudo certinho muito obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Renan, 
Como comentário, colocar * mesmo que você esteja pegando todos os campos em questão de performance não e a melhor opção. Veja se o código a baixo resolver e se não informe o que aconteceu, por favor.

```
SELECT Q5.* FROM tbl_TURMA AS Q1
LEFT JOIN tbl_PESSOA_TURMA AS Q2
ON Q1.COD_IDENT_TURMA = Q2.COD_IDENT_TURMA
LEFT JOIN tbl_PESSOAS AS Q3
ON Q2.COD_IDENT_PESSO = Q3.COD_IDENT_PESSO
WHERE Q2.COD_IDENT_PESSO = '38'
```

Tenta com esse colocando um subselect, nesse caso vai selecionar todos os codigo de pessoa que tem a mesma turma que o rapaz.

```
SELECT Q3.* FROM tbl_TURMA AS Q1
LEFT JOIN tbl_PESSOA_TURMA AS Q2
ON Q1.COD_IDENT_TURMA = Q2.COD_IDENT_TURMA
LEFT JOIN tbl_PESSOAS AS Q3
ON Q2.COD_IDENT_PESSO = Q3.COD_IDENT_PESSO
WHERE   Q2.COD_IDENT_PESSO = '38'
Q3.COD_IDENT_PESSO IN (SELECT COD_IDENT_PESSO FROM tbl_PESSOA_TURMA WHERE COD_IDENT_TURMA = Q2.COD_IDENT_TURMA)
```

Comment: Henrique está query so está retornando a turma que a pessoa está. Preciso que mostra para mim todas as PESSOAS da turma que ESTE "ALUNO" ESTÁ, para entender melhor preciso dos amigos de turma desse aluno, so para ilustrar.

Comment: E eu estou revendo e vejo que vai retornar apenas a pessoa. 
Mas para entender. A tabela tbl_TURMA ( Tem informação da turma) a tbl_PESSOAS ( Tem informação das pessoas) e a tabela tbl_PESSOA_TURMA ( e uma tabela de relacionamento n:m que tem o relacionamento entre a pessoa e a turma correto?

Comment: Correto. exatamente isto

Comment: Está mostrando o aluno a quantidade de vezes que aparece ele em uma turma, por exemplo estou tem duas turmas, meu nome e meus dados repetem 2 vezes.

Comment: Use o `GROUP BY tabela.campoturma` veja o campo turmar e veja se funcionar. Se não me informa que achamos outra solução.

Comment: Como ficaria o sql ?

Comment: Ainda sim está retornando apenas o valor replicado.

Comment: `SELECT Q3.* FROM tbl_TURMA AS Q1
LEFT JOIN tbl_PESSOA_TURMA AS Q2
 ON Q1.COD_IDENT_TURMA = Q2.COD_IDENT_TURMA
LEFT JOIN tbl_PESSOAS AS Q3
 ON Q2.COD_IDENT_PESSO = Q3.COD_IDENT_PESSO
WHERE   Q2.COD_IDENT_PESSO = '38'
 Q3.COD_IDENT_PESSO IN (SELECT COD_IDENT_PESSO FROM tbl_PESSOA_TURMA WHERE COD_IDENT_TURMA = Q2.COD_IDENT_TURMA)
GROUP BY Q2.COD_IDENT_PESSO`

Comment: Ainda não está funcionando. Tentar explicar melhor, Sou professor RENAN, porem também sou aluno, preciso de saber todos os alunos, que são da sala aonde eu sou professor, e os alunos da sala em que eu sou aluno, porem devemos tomar cuidado pois podem haver alunos que estão também nestas duas turmas.

Comment: O sql que você fez, está retornando apenas o grupo de turmas a qual eu digitei o código, preciso que retorne os alunos destas turmas.

Comment: Uai eu coloquei para ele agrupar pelo código da pessoa não da turma.
Faça um teste colocando para ele agrupar pelo código da turma, não dando vou pensar em outra maneira de ele não repetir.
`Q2.COD_IDENT_TURMA` acredito que mudando o agrupando inicial que fizemos para `GROUP BY Q3.COD_IDENT_PESSO` o detalhe ai era a tabela tenta ai pegando o codigo da pessoa da tabela q3