# SQL: Ordenar lista por números de votos de outra tabela

Tags: mysql, sql

Quero os resultados da minha enquete sejam ordenados pela a quantidade de votos que tem na outra tabela exclusiva para computar votos.

Atualmente meus resultados sai assim:
[image: resultado atual]

Tenho duas tabelas, essa abaixo pertence as respostas a ser votada.
A coluna *enquete_id* indica o número da enquete que está vinculada as respostas para votação.

```
CREATE TABLE `respostas` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `enquete_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `opcao` varchar(500) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

E essa tabela pertence aos votos, aqui é onde serão computados:

```
CREATE TABLE `votos` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `enquete_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `opcao_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `data` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

> Eu tentei algo assim, mas não da certo, até pela as vezes que deu, ***infelizmente não apareceu os votos zerados, sumiram as opções de votar que estavam sem votos.***

```
SELECT * 
FROM resposta op 
INNER JOIN votos vt ON (vt.enquete_id = op.enquete_id) 
WHERE op.enquete_id='1' 
GROUP BY op.id ORDER BY vt.opcao_id
```

[Referência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/181739/ordenar-pelo-n%C3%BAmero-de-repeti%C3%A7%C3%B5es-de-uma-coluna)

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Duvidas LEFT JOIN SQL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/85986/duvidas-left-join-sql)

Comment: Acho que é quase isso, mas ainda não conseguir fazer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"infelizmente não apareceu os votos zerados, sumiram as opções de votar que estavam sem votos"*.  Por essa descrição e pelo seu exemplo, o problema está no `join`.

Ao usar `INNER JOIN`, faz com que, **um registro relacionado exista os mesmos valores nas duas tabelas**, ou seja, o "enquete_id" deve existir em ambas as tabelas.

Para trazer os valores "zero" ou seja, sem votos, precisa fazer um `LEFT` join (se tiver dúvidas, veja essa pergunta: [qual é a diferença entre inner join e outer join](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6441/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-inner-join-e-outer-join)), mas dessa forma, caso o registro não exita na tabela "votos", irá retornal NULL, então pode usar a [function ifnull](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-ifnull/) para retornar zero no lugar de null, ficando assim a query parecida com isso:

```
SELECT COUNT(IFNULL(vt.enquete_id, 0)) votos
  FROM resposta op 
  LEFT JOIN votos vt ON (vt.enquete_id = op.enquete_id) 
 WHERE op.enquete_id='1' 
 GROUP BY op.id 
 ORDER BY vt.opcao_id, votos
```

**EDIT:** para o caso do exemplo, com os dados específicos aqui: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/309804/11 foi possível notar que é preciso fazer o join também com a opção votada, e nesse caso a query ficou assim:

```
SELECT op.*, COUNT(vt.opcao_id) votos
  FROM resposta op 
  LEFT JOIN votos vt ON vt.enquete_id = op.enquete_id
        AND vt.opcao_id = op.id
 WHERE op.enquete_id = 1 
 GROUP BY vt.enquete_id, vt.opcao_id
 ORDER BY votos DESC, op.opcao;
```

Comment: Faltou alterar o order para a quantidade de votos. penso q tb o SUM deva ser alterado por um count na tabela votos, não?

Comment: sim bem observado, eu coloquei a query que era pra dar a ideia geral, mas vou alterar ai fica direito, obrigado :)

Comment: Quase deu certo, mas ainda  não ordenou pelo o maior número de votos.

Comment: só mudar o order by para como precisa, pode ser só `votos desc` por exemplo

Comment: Veja a captura de tela de como está aparecendo: https://bit.ly/3nzLJsz Observa que o ID 44 tem 1 voto e ID 43 não tem votos, o ID 44 deveria estar acima do 43. Obs: coloquei um `op.*,` depois do `SELECT` para aparecer os demais elementos da tabela, estava aparecendo só "votos".

Comment: isso não mostra nada, vá aqui: http://sqlfiddle.com/  crie as tabelas e faça inserts com os valores que tem, ai fica mais fácil de ajudar

Comment: Segue o link do que você pediu: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/309804/1/0 fico muito agradecido se puder me ajudar.

Comment: vendo os dados ficou mais fácil, falta fazer o join tbm pela opção, veja minha resposta

Comment: deu foi certo! Obrigado!

Comment: não esqueça de aceitar a resposta :)

Comment: Detectei um novo problema: quando a enquete é nova e não tem votos em nenhuma opção, as opções pra votar não aparecem. Se você adicionar mais opções pra votar nesse teste do link, você verá que não irão aparecer. Fiz uma edição pra você ver: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fc4d23/2

Comment: se vc usar `*` no select não vai agrupar e tbm precisa incluir todo os campos que vai usar no `select` no `group by` para garantir que conta corretamente. Tem campos que não se repetem, como data e ip, e não fazem sentido estar na query, se quer contar ocorrencias. Veja esse exemplo de como resolver: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fc4d23/23   A pergunta ja etava aceita, se você removeu faça outra pergunta com outro problema, não faz sentido fazer isso e daqui a pouco isso vira um chat sem fim ok?

Comment: Opa! Mesmo com mais de 8 anos de experiência mexendo com PHP e SQL, eu nunca iria conseguir fazer uma query dessa. Obrigado, deu tudo certo e tive um grande aprendizado!